# Consequence of violating macOS's ARM64 calling convention

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64, calling-convention, abi

I'm porting some AArch64/ARM64/Apple Silicon assembly code from Linux to macOS.

This code uses all 31 available registers (stack pointer doesn't count) to avoid almost all cases of spilling; the Linux calling conventions allow me to use that many registers.

If pressed, I would admit that spilling one extra register (thus bringing it down to 30 registers used) is feasible as performance would be minimally affected, but if restricted to 29 or less available registers, performance would suffer considerably more. Thus, I'd really like to have at least 30 registers available, and ideally 31.

I just learned from [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms) official Apple document that two extra registers are reserved, beyond what the Linux calling conventions require:

> Respect the Purpose of Specific CPU Registers
>
> The ARM standard delegates certain decisions to platform designers. Apple platforms adhere to the following choices:
>
> - The platforms reserve register x18. Don’t use this register.
> - The frame pointer register (x29) must always address a valid frame record. Some functions — such as leaf functions or tail calls — may opt not to create an entry in this list As a result, stack traces are always meaningful, even without debug information.

Despite these claims, my code appears to run fine without it.

Now, I fully understand that ignoring such ABI requirements is a Very Bad Thing (TM). However, I'd like to understand exactly how the code may break due to the use of each of x18 and x29.

For instance, from reading the above documentation, my understanding is that x29 is there to support debugging or crash dumps. Suppose I didn't care about debugging this function in particular (which I actually don't), or whether any generated crash dumps are meaningful. In that case, is there any harm to using x29?

As for x18, any idea what is it used for? I'd hypothesize (with zero supporting evidence) that if an interrupt or context switch executes while this code is running, x18 is not saved, and thus corrupts the results of my function once it returns. That would be a more serious condition, and I'd heed the advice to not use x18 in that case.

Also note that the code in question is a leaf function, so there is no issue with breaking any functions called from within it.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that X18 is designated by ARM as the platform register, and is only a temporary register if the platform doesn't assign a purpose to it.

Comment: If you expect this to be stable or production code, anything beyond experiments, you should stick to the ABI. So many problems have been caused by developers relying on undefined behaviour that happened to work at one point in time, but later broke.

Comment: I vaguely remember from days when we ported aarch64-linux code to macos, that macos uses some register for svc calls or something like that. So content of that free to use register on linux was corrupted when code executed on macos and our library did not work properly. I don't remember if that was `x18` or some other. But for sure we did not bother with frame pointers stuff and that had no consequences.

Comment: A bit of searching led me to this page 'https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.31.3/osfmk/arm64/locore.s.auto.html' . It seems `x18` is involved in system calls and interrupt handlers after all.

Comment: @user3124812 I suppose it's not an issue with context switches. I spawned 12 copies of the executable that runs tests on my code (more than the 8 available cores on the M1), and adjusted the iterations to run for a few seconds each. Thus, context switches definitely happened while running, and yet all tests passed.

Comment: @swineone Also check if you can perhaps use a NEON register for one datum to free a conventional register.  Many operations are available on these.

Comment: @fuz good outside of the box thinking. Unfortunately, unless I'm able to operate directly on them (which isn't the case, the registers I'd replace first are used as pointers and loop counters), I'd have to move the data from the NEON register to a general purpose register and back. Doesn't save much over just spilling and reloading the register.

Comment: @swineone Surely not all registers you could replace are for loop counters and pointers?  If it's data, you can keep it in a NEON register and even do arithmetic and comparisons on it.  And I suppose you've already made use of the link register, too.

Comment: @fuz in my particular code, I have 30 variables that are all used often (too expensive to spill), plus a loop counter and a pointer which are more rarely used. I've already spilled the loop counter to arrive at 31 register used, and could conceivably spill the pointer to get to 30 at a little more cost. Spilling any of the other 30 variables would start to get expensive.

Comment: @swineone But couldn't you put any of the variables into a NEON register?  Or even all of them?

Comment: Does anyone know if godbolt supports generating ARM64 code with MacOS conventions, and if so what the necessary options are?

Comment: I'd like to check if perhaps it is used to address thread-local storage.

Comment: @NateEldredge try `-target arm64-apple-darwin` on one of the ARMv8-A clang compilers. I just did a quick test and it appears to work.

Comment: @swineone: Thanks.  Regrettably `thread-local storage is not supported for the current target` so I couldn't try my idea.

Comment: NEON registers can do integer math; e.g. if you want 32-bit integer ADD, you can do that in the bottom element of a SIMD register, with don't-care garbage in the high 1 or 3 elements of a 64-bit `d` or 128-bit `q` vector.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can safely clobber `x29` if broken backtraces are an acceptable loss to you.

`x18` is a different story.
On macOS, Rosetta uses it, so Apple can't clobber it anymore without at least refactoring that. They also [have a kernel test](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-7195.141.2/tests/x18.c.auto.html) to make sure `x18` is restored "on hardware that supports it". And so far, that is all hardware that support arm64 macOS, and all macOS versions that support Apple Silicon have this behaviour enabled.
On iOS though, there is hardware that does not support it, specifically the A11 chip series and older. On those chips, the kernel is configured with `__ARM_KERNEL_PROTECT__`, which enables a Spectre mitigation that uses `x18` *on all exception handlers, even async ones*, before the kernel gets a chance to spill any registers. So unless you're running with interrupts off, your `x18` can be zeroed at any point in time. In addition, even on A12 and later, iOS versions before iOS 14.0 did clobber `x18` intentionally.

Now if you checked out the linked test, you might be tempted to check the sysctl `hw.optional.arm_kernel_protect` at runtime, but unfortunately that is only exported on `DEVELOPMENT` and `DEBUG` configurations of XNU.

So if you're targeting iOS, you cannot use `x18`. If you're targeting macOS, then you can use it for the time being, but that may change in the future. You could try and detect such change by doing the same thing the test does: set `x18` to a certain value, call `sched_yield()`, then check the value. But again, that relies on all exceptions treating `x18` the same, and while they currently do, that too may change in the future.

| Update |
| --- |
| macOS 13 did indeed change this! While macOS 11 and 12 would unconditionally preserve `x18`, macOS 13 now has more complicated rules. `x18` is now only preserved for [processes running under Rosetta](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/osfmk/arm64/pcb.c#L334-L345) as well as [processes that were either built against a macOS 12 SDK or older, or hold the `com.apple.private.uexc` or `com.apple.private.custom-x18-abi` entitlements](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/osfmk/arm64/machine_task.c#L272-L287). The same rules apply to iOS 16, with the caveats that there is no Rosetta and you cannot run binaries built against the macOS SDK. So as of iOS 16, `x18` has to be considered off-limits again for all devices. |

Comment: I'm curious - what does the "hardware that supports it" mean - hardware that supports using the x18 register? Shouldn't that be all AArch64 CPUs? Or what was lacking on A11 and older?

Comment: It just means that it has to be used to mitigate microarchitectural attacks. If you ran your own kernel on such HW, then x18 would be perfectly usable.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's fine to use x29 for anything you like if you don't want working backtraces.

When Apple started out with aarch64 on iOS, they didn't yet have any specific use in mind for x18 quite yet, but they wanted to keep it reserved, to make sure people don't accidentally end up relying on it. So back then, the kernel clobbered x18, setting it to some nonzero bogus value on every context switch, just so that it would be very clear to everybody that you can't use it.

Since the arrival of macOS on Apple Silicon, they did remove the piece of code that intentionally clobbers this register though. I'm not sure if this is because they have actually found a specific use for the register somewhere (so they can't have the kernel clobber it), or have just chosen to play nicer regarding it. (It does help for e.g. userspace emulating Windows executables with Wine though - in Windows, x18 is supposed to always be a pointer pointing towards the TEB, thread environment block.)

So while x18 does seem to empirically be usable on macOS today, it's not sure if it works on iOS, and it can be used for something, so I would recommend against using that.